# BVP sine-Gordon problem solved with Runge Kutta

Tags: partial-differential-equations, runge-kutta-methods

We have the following BVP on xgrid [-2,2] and tgrid[0,4]
$$
u_{tt} -u_{xx} + \text{sin}(u)=0, u(x,0) = \sin(\pi x)^2e^{-x^2}, u_t(x,0)=\sin(\pi x)^4e^{-x^2},
0=u(-2,t)=u(2,t)
$$
and we have to solve it using RK4. We semi-discretize $u_{xx}$ such that we can write the equation as $$u_{tt} = Lu - \sin(u)$$ where $L = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$, and then we let $u=v$, $v_t=w$, and $w_t=Av-\sin(v)$
$$
(w_t) = v_{tt} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\ddot{v_1} \\
\ddot{v_2} \\
\vdots\\
\vdots \\
\ddot{v_M} \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{h^2} \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix} 
-2 & 1 &  \\
1 & -2 & 1 \\
& \ddots & \ddots & \ddots  \\
 & & 1 & -2 & 1 \\
 & & & 1 & -2 
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2 \\
\vdots \\
\vdots \\
v_{M}
\end{bmatrix}
+
\frac{1}{h^2} \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
f_1(t) \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
0 \\
f_2(t)
\end{bmatrix}
- \sin
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2 \\
\vdots \\
\vdots \\
v_M \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$\

How would we proceed from here with time-integration with RK4? We later also need to find an approximaton for $u_x$, to find the energy of the system.

Comment: You can easily generalize my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60405185/is-there-a-better-way-to-tidy-this-chuck-of-code-it-is-the-runge-kutta-4th-orde to this case, see also https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/34330/6839 for more supporting formulas.

Comment: Thanks dude! It converges with an order 2, does this make sense because of the discretiszation?

Comment: You should get 4th order convergence towards the space-discretized or method-of-lines (MoL) exact solution, for instance by computing the error using Richardson extrapolation in time direction for a constant space grid. The MoL-exact solution indeed has an error $O(h^2)$ to the exact solution of the PDE.